# Flask-admin how to add button beside rows

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I make a tuition payment app using **Flask** and using **Flask-admin** to managing the payment.

**Flask-Admin** automatically generated rows of tables by the SQLAlchemy that I declared on my models.py

Here is the image of my table:
[image]
Now I want to give a button beside the every **total bill** number for checkout purpose the bill.

I know how to add columns with **column_list** method that provide by **ModelView**, as I try like this code below:

```
column_list = ('student_id', 'total_bill', 'Pay Now')
```

and it will give the view display like this:
[image]
Now I want column **Pay Now** have a button for every that rows like I code manually with **HTML** like this:
[image]
There is have checkout button for every rows, as I mentioned above this purpose is for the checkout button.

So, how to do that..?, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You can add custom row action buttons like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037226/additional-action-button-doesnt-work-on-flask-admin. It is possible to give it a custom layout but it is slightly different from what you are looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [column_formatters](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/?highlight=column_formatters#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters) to render the column whichever way you wish.

Example code on Github, [flask-admin-row-form](https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-admin-row-form).

For example, each row "Checkout" button could be rendered as a HTML form with a submit button and the student id rendered as a hidden field within the form.

Simple example below (Python 2.7), files all reside in the root directory. `views.py` contains the important code, the rest is straightforward Flask stuff.

[image]

Class `StudentView` defines a method `_format_pay_now` which either renders a string "Paid" if the model's `is_paid` value is `True` or otherwise a HTML form.

Class `StudentView` also exposes a route `'/admin/student/checkout'` via the method `checkout_view` to process the submitted form. In this particular instance the `is_paid` column is set True and the list view re-rendered.

**views.py**

```
from flask import redirect, flash, url_for
from flask_admin import expose
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin.helpers import get_form_data
from flask_admin.babel import gettext
from markupsafe import Markup


class StudentView(sqla.ModelView):

    page_size = 5

    column_list = ('id', 'cost', 'Pay Now')
    column_editable_list = ['cost']

    # override the column labels
    column_labels = {
        'id': 'Student ID',
        'cost': 'Total Bill',
    }

    def _format_pay_now(view, context, model, name):

        if model.is_paid:
            return 'Paid'

        # render a form with a submit button for student, include a hidden field for the student id
        # note how checkout_view method is exposed as a route below
        checkout_url = url_for('.checkout_view')

        _html = '''
            <form action="{checkout_url}" method="POST">
                <input id="student_id" name="student_id"  type="hidden" value="{student_id}">
                <button type='submit'>Checkout</button>
            </form
        '''.format(checkout_url=checkout_url, student_id=model.id)

        return Markup(_html)

    column_formatters = {
        'Pay Now': _format_pay_now
    }

    @expose('checkout', methods=['POST'])
    def checkout_view(self):

        return_url = self.get_url('.index_view')

        form = get_form_data()

        if not form:
            flash(gettext('Could not get form from request.'), 'error')
            return redirect(return_url)

        # Form is an ImmutableMultiDict
        student_id = form['student_id']

        # Get the model from the database
        model = self.get_one(student_id)

        if model is None:
            flash(gettext('Student not not found.'), 'error')
            return redirect(return_url)

        # process the model
        model.is_paid = True

        try:
            self.session.commit()
            flash(gettext('Student, ID: {student_id}, set as paid'.format(student_id=student_id)))
        except Exception as ex:
            if not self.handle_view_exception(ex):
                raise

            flash(gettext('Failed to set student, ID: {student_id}, as paid'.format(student_id=student_id), error=str(ex)), 'error')

        return redirect(return_url)
```

**models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cost = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    is_paid = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "ID: {id}; Cost : {cost}".format(id=self.id, cost=self.cost)
```

**commands.py**

Use `flask create-database` to generate the SQLite database.

```
import random
from flask.cli import click, with_appcontext
from models import db, Student


@click.command('create-database')
@with_appcontext
def create_database():

    # Create 100 students

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    for _ in range(0, 100):
        _project = Student(
            cost=random.randrange(10, 200),
            is_paid=False
        )
        db.session.add(_project)

    db.session.commit()
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from models import db, Student
from commands import create_database

app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

# Create in-memory database
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
db.init_app(app)

app.cli.add_command(create_database)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


from views import StudentView

admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(StudentView(Student, db.session))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Click==7.0
enum34==1.1.6
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.17
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.2.1
```